# tensor products of noetherian domains

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Under what conditions is the tensor product of two non-commutative Noetherian domains also a Noetherian domain? To be more precise about the problem, I am looking at rings of fractions on such tensor products, as a method of generalising the coaction of a Hopf algebra $H$ on an algebra $A$. Thus the coaction on an element of $A$ may lie in a ring of fractions on $A\otimes H$ rather than just $A\otimes H$. Any useful information on this would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Tensor product over what?

Comment: For standard coaction of Hopf algebras it would just be the field.

Comment: If $K$ is algebraically closed then a Noetherian domain is always of the form $K[X]$ for some irreducible affine variety $X$. The tensor product $K[X]\otimes_K K[Y]$ is isomorphic with $K[X\times Y]$, which is again a Neotherian domain. The only problem which might arise is when $K$ is not algebraically closed: for example if $L$ is a finite extension of $K$ then $L\otimes_K L$ is not a domain. Is the ground field algebraically closed in your case?

Comment: Apologies - I should say that for Hopf algebras the interesting case is where the algebras are non-commutative.

Comment: @Ehud Meir: for you, $K[[T]]$ is not a Noetherian domain?

Comment: Maybe you known the example, but $ F=k(x_i:i\in I)$ is a Noetherian domain because it is a field, but $F\otimes F$ is not Noetherian if I is infinite.